# Bootstrap MaxCDN with integrity not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap.css when included along with `integrity` and `crossorigin` options doesn't work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

However, removing those options worked. Does it mean integrity is not valid?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using what is listed on bootstrapcdn.com which includes a `sha256` and `sha512`.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Update we now just advertise `sha384`.